# Passar parâmetro sem especificar o tipo da variável a receber na função

Tags: java

Estou a criar uma função em Java que retorna o tipo da variável e como tal, uma vez que estou a tentar desvendar o seu tipo, não tenho maneira de dizer à função que tipo de variável esperar.

O que estou a tentar construir é o seguinte:

```
public String getVarType(AnyType var){
    if (var instanceof ArrayList) {
        return "ArrayList";
    }
    if (var instanceof String) {
        return "String";
    }
}
```

Como posso definir nos parâmetros para a função esperar qualquer tipo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se você está querendo saber o tipo do objeto, trabalhe com `Object`. Afinal, toda classe Java é subclasse de Object implicitamente. Para checar o tipo do objeto, você pode criar um método para isto:

```
public String getObjectName(Object o){
   return o.getClass().getSimpleName(); 
}
```

No qual ao ser chamado resutará em:

```
getObjectName(new ArrayList()); // ArrayList
getObjectName(new String()); //String

String abc = "abc";
getObjectName(abc); // String
```

Há um porem, se você tentar usar o método acima com uma variável `int a = 10;` o retorno será `10`. Pelo que pesquisei não tem como obter o tipo de dados primitivos por questões óbvias.

Se a sua aplicação necessita fazer essa comparação, você pode trabalhar com classes numéricas (`Integer` para `int`, `Double` para `double`, etc...), nesses casos o método mencionado acima funcionaria.

```
Integer integer = 10;
System.out.println(getObjectType(integer)); // Integer
```

#### [Funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@reebr/Passar-parametro-sem-especificar-o-tipo-da-variavel-a-recebe)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim.

```
public String getVarType(String var){
        return "String";
}
public String getVarType(ArrayList var){
       return "ArrayList";
}
```

Comment: eu sei, mas esse método pode retornar um erro fatal caso eu me esqueça de validar algum tipo de variável. por isso é que estou a recorrer ao `if` para poder recorrer ao `else`