# Como obter o tipo de componente clicado?

Tags: java, swing, awt

O método getSource() retorna a fonte do evento, existe algum método que retorne o tipo da fonte do evento, se foi um jlabel, ou jbutton, algo do tipo?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46579/4808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode usar o instanceof em um if, checando qual a classe que pertence o objeto, exemplo:

```
if(getSource() instanceof JButton){
//Foi clicado em um botão
}
else if(getSource() instanceof JLabel){
//Foi clicado em uma JLabel
}
```

Comment: `instanceof` irá retornar verdadeiro se o objeto for uma instância da classe ou de alguma subclasse. Se você não precisar de verificação para subclasses prefira `getClass()` pois há ganho de desempenho.

Answer (score 2):

Suponha que você tenha uma variável `_var` que armazena a fonte do evento, obtida a partir de getSource().

Você pode obter o tipo dessa variável (e de qualquer outra) com getClass(). A comparação pode ser feita assim:

```
_var.getClass() == JButton.class
```